# How to Convert This Jquery Script to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script is written in jquery to fix table header when scrolling but for some reason i can't use jquery script, i searched for converters but nothing found, if there any tool available please tell me or if someone make it work without jquery that would be great.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fixMe = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $t_fixed;

            function init() {
                $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
                $t_fixed = $this.clone();
                $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
                resizeFixed();
            }

            function resizeFixed() {
                $t_fixed.find("th").each(function (index) {
                    $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
                });
            }

            function scrollFixed() {
                var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                    tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
                    tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
                if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom) $t_fixed.hide();
                else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden")) $t_fixed.show();
            }
            $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
            $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
            init();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").fixMe();
    $(".up").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: "but for some reason i can't use jquery script" I would be looking to answer that question if you're not sure why.

Comment: Well as a first approach you could manually go through and figure out how each jQuery component works and how you could replicate that in JavaScript...

Comment: Doing a re-write without jquery is a lot of work here.  I'd suggest hiring a programmer.  Or you could tell us why you can't use jQuery.  If that is the "problem"  then I have a solution.  Make sure this script is after the jQuery load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool which convert `jquery` into `javascript`, `jquery` is not `language` its a `library`. It will be great if you understand each line of your code then find the way of doing that in javascript.

You will get a lot of article which help to convert your code.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery looks good to me. I think you forgot to load the jquery api. Try adding the following inside your head tags before any jquery runs.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wanted to comment this but I can't as I don't have enough reputation :(